# Any finite index subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ is open

Tags: topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to show that every finite index subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z_p$ is open.  Since $H$ has finite index, it is equivalent (and perhaps easier) to show that it is closed.  But I've tried showing that, and I can't work out how to use the finite index condition at any point.

Another thing I tried was showing that any non-closed subgroup $K$ of $\mathbb Z_p$ must have infinite index, by using non-convergent sequences in $K$ to construct infinitely many cosets.  But I don't think it's obvious even that $\mathbb Z$ has infinite index in $\mathbb Z_p$ (apart from using a cardinality argument that might not generalize to general non-closed subgroups).

As far as I'm aware, this is a property that is not shared by general profinite groups.  So any proof must use some other part of the structure of $\mathbb Z_p$ in an essential way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've voted to close the question, since it's answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092974/finite-index-subgroup-g-of-mathbbz-p-is-open?rq=1).

For completeness, the answer is:

Let $n=[\mathbb Z_p:H]$.  We claim that $n\mathbb Z_p\subset H$.  But this is just Lagrange's theorem applied to the quotient group $\mathbb Z_p/H$.

Now it can be shown that $[\mathbb Z_p:n\mathbb Z_p]=|n|_p^{-1}$.  So if $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $m$ then $[\mathbb Z_p:n\mathbb Z_p]=p^{k}=[\mathbb Z_p:p^k\mathbb Z_p]$.  Therefore, $n\mathbb Z_p=p^k\mathbb Z_p\subset H$, so $H$ is open.

Comment: Sorry for the such a late reply, but could you explain on why $p^k\mathbb{Z}_p \subset H$ implies that $H$ is open? It seems that $p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open, but how does this suffice to show $H$ is open? P.S. I have seen in many contexts that when proving a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ (usually a profinite group) is open, we show that it contains an open subgroup of $G$. But why it suffices? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $H_n=H+p^n\mathbb Z_p$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ genarated by $H$ together with $p^n$. Let $a_n=[\mathbb Z_p:H_n]$. Then from $H\subseteq H_{n+1}\subseteq H_n$ we see that the seequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nondecreasing and bounded from above by $[\mathbb Z_p:H]$, hence it is eventually constant, say $a_n=a_N$ for all $n\ge N$.
But then $[\mathbb Z_p:H_{n}]=[\mathbb Z_p:H_N][H_N:H_{n}]$  implies that also $H_n=H_N$ for $n\ge N$. Therefore
$$H=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}H_n = H_0\cap H_1\cap \ldots\cap H_N = H_N, $$
which immediately gives us $p^N\mathbb Z_p\subseteq H$.

Comment: Please could you explain the last part of this?  I can see why $(a_n($ is a non-decreasing sequence and bounded by $[\mathbb Z_p:X]$, but it's not clear to me why that means that the constant value the sequence attains is equal to $[\mathbb Z_p:H]$ or why that means that $(p^n)\subset H$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Rewritten accordingly, I hope

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite.  I'm still not sure, though, why we have that $H=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} H_n$.

Comment: For example, what's stopping some element $x\in\mathbb Z_p$ from getting arbitrarily close to elements of $H$ - in the sense that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $h_\epsilon\in H$ with $|x-h_\epsilon|_p<\epsilon$, but not being itself an element of $H$?  Such an element $x$ would be contained in $\bigcap H_n$ but not in $H$.