# If $[\mathbb Z_p:H]=n$ then $n\mathbb Z_p< H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that If $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ of a finite index, then $H = p^i\mathbb Z_p$ for some $i\in\mathbb N$.
Here, $\mathbb Z_p$ is the p-adic integers.

My problem is showing the following:
If $[\mathbb Z_p:H]=n$ then $n\mathbb Z_p<H$

I've encountered the accepted answer here: [Any finite index subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264473/any-finite-index-subgroup-of-mathbb-z-p-is-open?noredirect=1&lq=1)
In which the writer states that this result follows from applying Lagrange's theorem to the quotient group $\mathbb Z_p/H$ but I couldn't quite understand how.

(Though they're kinda old posts, I tried commenting here [Finite index subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092974/finite-index-subgroup-g-of-mathbbz-p-is-open?noredirect=1&lq=1) to get clarifications but with no response..)

Comment: If $G$ is a group of order $n$, then $g^n=e$ for all $g$ in $G$. That's in multiplicative notation. In additive notation, we'd write $nx=0$ for all $x$ in $G$. Apply this with the quotient group $\Bbb Z_p/H$ to say that $nxH=H$ for all $xH$ in $\Bbb Z_p/H$ (as $H$ is the additive identity), which is equivalent to $nx$ in $H$ for all $x$ in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Nice! thank you :-) Just to be certain, shouldn't it be $nx+H=H$?

Comment: Err, yes. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p, \ $  take any nonzero $x$ in $H$, then note that $ \ x \mathbb{Z}< H$ and $ \ x \mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $ \ x\mathbb{Z}_p$ as $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

So H contains  $x\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Now $x\mathbb{Z}_p= p^{v(x)}\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $v$ is p-adic valuation, so $H$ is between $p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some nonnegative integer $n$.

So $H$ is of the form $p^i\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ i.e., $$H=p^i \mathbb{Z}_p, \ \ i \in \mathbb{N}.$$

This answers your question.